# How do you deny creating copy of instance in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

In past, at one job interview I had test question "How do you deny creating copy of class instance (object)?".

My answer was to use Singleton patter in the first place while it deny creation of instance at all.

But when I was recently thinking about it, I guess it was not the best answer. Now I think using `private` scope for `__clone()` class method would be a better solution. This way it allows at least creating new instance.

But I am thinking, is there any other way how to do it? If Singleton is not used or private scope is not set, is there any better practice how to deny creation of copy of instance?

Comment: If you `clone` a class instance and a `__clone` method is present, the `__clone` method will be called. If it is private, the clone will fail. https://3v4l.org/IaXfI If you want to deny cloning an instance, this is the only way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is another option. Making the __clone() private will cause the following when cloning:

PHP7.x
FATAL ERROR Uncaught Error: Call to private A::__clone() from context

PHP5.x
FATAL ERROR Call to private A::__clone() from context

So if you want your code to behave exactly the same among different PHP versions you could do the following:

```
<?php

class A {
    public function __clone() {
        throw new Exception('Not allowed to be cloned');
    }
}

$a = new A;
try {
    $b = clone $a;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage(); //Not allowed to be cloned
}
```

Or more "fancy" one:

```
trait NotClonable {
    public function __clone() {
            throw new Exception('Not allowed to be cloned');
    }
}
class A {
    use NotClonable;
}
```

Comment: This kind of thing is perfect for a `trait` since it's very easy to re-use across many classes and isn't specific to the class itself.